# How to center my login div

Tags: html, css

I have a login page but am having problem  putting the login box inbetween the header nad the footer without scroll bars present. below is my web page

the login box seems to be floating and example is below
[image: web page floating login box]

What I wish to do is center the login box in between the header and footer and I don't want it to be scrollable.my css code and html  is below

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: white; /* fallback for old browsers 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
 
}

footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


header {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="bgm-green m-b-30">
        <ul class="h-inner">
            <li class="hi-logo m-10" >
                <img id="logo-image" class="logo-image" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </li>

            <li class="pull-right">
     <h2 class="c-white m-r-15 f-300"></h2>
   </li>
           
    </header>

    <section id="content" class="bgm-white">
        <div >
            <div class="login-page">
                <div class="form">
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="checker" type="checkbox" value="">
                            <i class="input-helper"></i>
                            <span>Remember me</span>
                        </label>
                        <button>login</button>
                        <p class="message">Unable to login? Contact our admin <a href="#">here</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer class="bgm-green">
        <div class="c-white">
            Copyright &copy; 2016 First High Tower Infotech
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Older IE warning message -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <div class="ie-warning">
                <h1 class="c-white">Warning!!</h1>
                <p>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer, please upgrade <br/>to any of the following web browsers to access this website.</p>
                <div class="iew-container">
                    <ul class="iew-download">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/chrome.png" alt="">
                                <div>Chrome</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/firefox.png" alt="">
                                <div>Firefox</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.opera.com">
                                <img src="img/browsers/opera.png" alt="">
                                <div>Opera</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.apple.com/safari/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/safari.png" alt="">
                                <div>Safari</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">
                                <img src="img/browsers/ie.png" alt="">
                                <div>IE (New)</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>Sorry for the inconvenience!</p>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>
            <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script data-main="lib/js/config" src="lib/js/Requirejs.js"></script>

    <script>
  require(['config'], function(){
   require(['js/loaders/loginloader']);
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You put CSS in place of HTML in your snippet :-P

Comment: down voter kindly state how I can improve on it and give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.login-page` to make it in the center of the page.

Just like:

```
.login-page {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or have a look at the snippet below:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: white; /* fallback for old browsers 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
 
}

footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


header {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.login-page {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header class="bgm-green m-b-30">
    <ul class="h-inner">
        <li class="hi-logo m-10" >
            <img id="logo-image" class="logo-image" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </li>

        <li class="pull-right">
             <h2 class="c-white m-r-15 f-300">Lagos State House of Assembly e-Parliament Management System</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section id="content" class="bgm-white">
    <div >
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="login-form">
                    <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></span>
                        <div class="fg-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></span>
                        <div class="fg-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input id="checker" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <i class="input-helper"></i>
                        <span>Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                    <button>login</button>
                    <p class="message">Unable to login? Contact our admin <a href="#">here</a></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<footer class="bgm-green">
    <div class="c-white">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 First High Tower Infotech
    </div>
</footer>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @alexdavies Check my updated answer, it has the snippet inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Edited your markup and snippet a little to remove some errors.

Answer to your question is just add `margin: auto;` to your login div CSS

```
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: white; /* fallback for old browsers 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
 
}

footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


header {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header class="bgm-green m-b-30">
    <ul class="h-inner">
        <li class="hi-logo m-10" >
            <img id="logo-image" class="logo-image" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </li>

        <li class="pull-right">
             <h2 class="c-white m-r-15 f-300">System</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>

<section id="content" class="bgm-white">
    <div >
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="login-form">
                    <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></span>
                        <div class="fg-line">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></span>
                        <div class="fg-line">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input id="checker" type="checkbox" value="">
                        <i class="input-helper"></i>
                        <span>Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                    <button>login</button>
                    <p class="message">Unable to login? Contact our admin <a href="#">here</a></p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<footer class="bgm-green">
    <div class="c-white">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 First High Tower Infotech
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you see it centered in the code snippet ? If it doesn't in your local, it means there are some other styles which are interfering with the login div. Check your browser Dev tools to see which styles are getting applied

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:-

```css
body{
 background-color:#9F3;
 margin:44px 0px 0px 0px;
 }
div#header{
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:20px;
 color: #F00;
 background-color:#603;
 padding:8px;
 
 }
 .aa{
 width:300px;
 height:240px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:40px;
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-left:50px;
 border-radius:15px;
 -webkit-border-radius:15px;
 -o-border-radius:15px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px;
 color:#FFF;
 font-weight:bold;
 box-shadow:inset -4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 }
.aa input[type="text"]{
 width:200px;
 height:35px;
 border:0;
 border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -o-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 padding-left:5px;
 }
.aa input[type="password"]{
 width:200px;
 height:35px;
 border:0;
 border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -o-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 padding-left:5px;
 }
.aa input[type="submit"]{
 width:100px;
 height:35px;
 border:0;
 border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
 -o-border-radius:5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 background-color:#0FC;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
 
div#footer{
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 width:100%;
 height:20px;
 color: #F00;
 background-color:#603;
 padding:8px;
 
 }
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>

 <div class="aa">
<h1>Login</h1>
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Username"><br><br>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Please Enter Password"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
 
</form>
</div>
 <div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: If you want you can add logo in header & footer & login form as backgroung-image.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: white; /* fallback for old browsers 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
 
}

footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}


header {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header class="bgm-green m-b-30">
        <ul class="h-inner">
            <li class="hi-logo m-10" >
                <img id="logo-image" class="logo-image" src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </li>

            <li class="pull-right">
     <h2 class="c-white m-r-15 f-300"></h2>
   </li>
           
    </header>

    <section id="content" class="bgm-white">
        <div >
            <div class="login-page">
                <div class="form">
                    <form class="login-form">
                        <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group m-b-20">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></span>
                            <div class="fg-line">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input id="checker" type="checkbox" value="">
                            <i class="input-helper"></i>
                            <span>Remember me</span>
                        </label>
                        <button>login</button>
                        <p class="message">Unable to login? Contact our admin <a href="#">here</a></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <footer class="bgm-green">
        <div class="c-white">
            Copyright &copy; 2016 First High Tower Infotech
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Older IE warning message -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <div class="ie-warning">
                <h1 class="c-white">Warning!!</h1>
                <p>You are using an outdated version of Internet Explorer, please upgrade <br/>to any of the following web browsers to access this website.</p>
                <div class="iew-container">
                    <ul class="iew-download">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/chrome.png" alt="">
                                <div>Chrome</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/firefox.png" alt="">
                                <div>Firefox</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.opera.com">
                                <img src="img/browsers/opera.png" alt="">
                                <div>Opera</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://www.apple.com/safari/">
                                <img src="img/browsers/safari.png" alt="">
                                <div>Safari</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie">
                                <img src="img/browsers/ie.png" alt="">
                                <div>IE (New)</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>Sorry for the inconvenience!</p>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- Placeholder for IE9 -->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>
            <script src="vendors/bower_components/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <script data-main="lib/js/config" src="lib/js/Requirejs.js"></script>

    <script>
  require(['config'], function(){
   require(['js/loaders/loginloader']);
  });
 </script>
</body>
```